Mithril app crashing when open multiple tabs/popups
I'm working on a project using Mithril, and on a table whenever I click an element it opens a popup Component which is basically composed by 4 divs nested into each other and the deepest one is another list.
The problem is that whenever I open the 9th popup the app breaks. Is there a way to optimize the usage of memory so I can open more popups? (That's an important functionality for this project to be able to open more popups).
There's about 5 to 6 API calls for each popup depending on which element was opened.

Maybe you could include some example code.  Also you say "tabs" in the title but then you say "popups" in the body of the question.  Do you mean browser tabs or do you mean a modal/popup in a single browser tab/window?

It occurs in both cases, it's a bit complicated to put some example code because it's a monolith, but the main concept is that whenever the component is rendered up to 6 api calls are made, and it's overloading the browser capacity leading to the app crashing.

Please try to include a reproduce-able example as well as which API calls you are talking about.  It seems to work fine for me.  Maybe also include which version of mithril you are using and a rough estimate of the amount of components you are trying to render on each draw.

Maybe you can provide more information here is a simple example that just opens popups with close buttons in them.  This assumes mithril is loaded on the page and accessible via m.
<div id="app">
</div>
<script>
function App() {
  let zindex=1, top=200, left=20, popups=[];
  
  function openAnotherPopup(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    zindex += 1;
    top += 20;
    left += 20;
    let ourIndex = popups.length;
    let popup = {zindex, top, left}
    function closer(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      popups.splice(popups.indexOf(popup), 1);
    }
    popup.closer = closer;
    popups.push(popup);
  }
  return {
    view: function () {
      return m('', 
         m('', popups.map(function (popup) { 
          return m(Popup, {popup: popup}); 
        })),
         m('button', {onclick: openAnotherPopup}, 'Popup'));
    }
  }
}

function Popup() {
  return {
    view: function ({attrs: {popup: {closer, zindex, top, left}}}) {
      let style = {
          zIndex: zindex,
          position: 'absolute', 
          top: top + 'px',
          left: left + 'px',
        };
      return m('div', {
        style: style
      },  m('div', m('div', m('div', m('button', {onclick: closer}, 'close')))));
    }
  }
}

m.mount(document.getElementById('app'), App);
</script>

